# Batch creation of folders

Tags: python, directory, mkdir

I am trying to script a function in which it will creates a list of folders and sub-folders.

While my code is as follows, I was wondering if there are any better methods for me to create the sub-folders? (See `createFolders` function line 5 onwards)

Not that the naming of the sub-folders will be changed but currently I am hard-coding it which can be a pain if I have to create more main/sub-folders...

```
import os

directory = '/user_data/TEST'

def createFolders():
    mainItems = ['Project_Files', 'Reference', 'Images']
    for mainItem in mainItems:
        os.makedirs(directory + '/' + str(mainItem))

    projDir = directory + '/' + str(mainItems[0])
    projItems = ['scene', 'assets', 'renders', 'textures']
    for projItem in projItems:
        os.makedirs(projDir + '/' + str(projItem))

if not os.path.exists(directory):
    print '>>> Creating TEST directory'
    os.makedirs(directory)
else:
    print '>>> TEST exists!'

createFolders()
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Does the code work as you expect it? If that is the case, then this question should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `os.path.join` to concatenate paths. `str` is unnecessary. You can use nested lists, to define the structure of subfolders:

```
import os

directory = '/user_data/TEST'

def create_folders(basedir, subfolders):
    for subfolder in subfolders:
        if isinstance(subfolder, (list, tuple)):
            create_folders(os.path.join(basedir, subfolder[0]), subfolder[1])
        else:
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(basedir, subfolder))

create_folders(directory, [
    ('Project_Files', ['scene', 'assets', 'renders', 'textures']),
    'Reference', 'Images'])
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) makedirs is **recursive directory creation function** what means it creates a full path you pass to it. So instead of making loops for sub-folders you can just create a list of all path's  you need and pass them to os.makedirs one by one e.g.:

```
folders = ['/user_data/TEST/Project_Files/scene', '/user_data/TEST/Project_Files/assets', '/user_data/TEST/Project_Files/renders', '/user_data/TEST/Project_Files/textures']
for path in folders:
    os.makedirs(path)
```

Comment: Yep, just the "leaf" directories need to be defined, nicely caught.

Comment: @Alexey This is not exactly what I wanted as this will means I will need to type in a lot of lines to define the directory. But I understand what you are trying to do here. Thanks!